# ES2015 class variable scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a class like the following:

```
class SomeService {

    constructor() {
        this.classVar= [];
    }

    aFunction() {
        myArray.forEach(function(obj) {
            // how can I access classVar within this scope
        });
    }
```

So my question is how can I access the `classVar` variable within `forEach` block? what is the recommended approach here?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.forEach(callback[, thisArg])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `this` context to the `forEach` function:

```
myArray.forEach(function(obj) {
    console.log(this.classVar);
}, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the reference to `self`

```
class SomeService {

    constructor() {
        this.classVar= [];
    }

    aFunction(myArray) {
        var self = this; //copy this to self
        myArray.forEach(function(obj) {
           self.classVar.push(obj);
        });
    }
}
```

**Demo**

```js
class SomeService {
  constructor() {
    this.classVar = [];
  }
  aFunction(myArray) {
    var self = this;
    myArray.forEach(function(obj) {
      // how can I access classVar within this scope
      self.classVar.push(obj)
    });
  }
}
var obj = new SomeService(); 
obj.aFunction([1,2]);
console.log(obj);
```